# Explode string only once on first occurring substring

Tags: php, arrays, split, explode, preg-split

`preg_match()` gives one match.
`preg_match_all()` returns all matches.
`preg_split()` returns all splits.

How can I split only on the first match?

Example:

```
preg_split("~\n~", $string);
```

This is what I want:

```
array(
  0 => 'first piece',
  1 => 'the rest of the string
        without any further splits'
)
```

Comment: If you are just doing using \n to split into an array you can use explode. It's slightly faster than preg_split.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply set $limit to `2` for 2 parts of the array. Thanks to @BenJames for mentioning:

```
preg_split("~\n~", $string, 2);
```

I tested and it works fine.

The limit argument:

> *If specified, then only substrings up to limit  are returned with the rest of the string being placed in the last substring. A limit  of -1, 0 or null means "no limit" and, as is standard across PHP, you can use null to skip to the flags  parameter.*

Answer (score 6):

Just add the limit flag

```
preg_split("~\n~", $string, 2);
```

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

> If specified, then only substrings up
>   to limit  are returned with the rest
>   of the string being placed in the last
>   substring.

Comment: You can't, because it substrings.

Comment: Mauris: the meaning of your comment is not clear, please explain

Answer (score 0):

There is a fair amount of nuance to such a seemingly simple task.  Different techniques can fail or offer skewed results in fringe scenarios.  It is important to understand the quality of the input string and your desired output for fringe cases when deciding on a technique.

The long story short, I would probably be using `trim()` to sanitize any leading or trailing whitespace characters.  I would use `preg_split()` with `\R` in the pattern to consistently match different newline sequences across different environments.  A quantifier of `+` (one or more) will provide additional stability in case there are consecutive newline characters.

```
var_export(
    preg_split('~\R+~', trim($string), 2)
);
```

The above will generate a two-element array (neither of which will be empty) when at least one newline sequence occurs and a one-element array when no newline sequence occurs.

Can `explode("\n", $string, 2)` be enough to satisfy?  Yes, sure, but again it comes down to the quality of the input and the desired output.

Here is a battery of test cases and some different techniques to compare the good, the bad and the ugly: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/KlssN).

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a server to test this on. Try:

```
preg_split("~\n~",$string,1);
```

The 1 represents the limit:

> Limit: If specified, then only
>   substrings up to limit  are returned
>   with the rest of the string being
>   placed in the last substring. A limit 
>   of -1, 0 or null means "no limit" and,
>   as is standard across PHP, you can use
>   null to skip to the flags  parameter.

Comment: it substrings, you can't use the $limit flag.

Comment: A limit of 1 will not split the string at all.

Comment: @Ben: I could obviously be wrong, but when applying the manual to Albus' requested, and assuming a limit of one, it would read as:

"If specified, then only substrings up to 1 are returned with the rest of the string being placed in the last substring."

To me that implies that regardless of the limit you specify (eg. $limit), there will always be a resulting substring with a value of $limit+1 which contains the remainder of the content.

Comment: Based on RMcLeod's accepted response, I conceed defeat on this one. Even 'rtfm' doesn't work with me, as I misunderstand it :-)